# How to delete the first 2 lines from string in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like the following:

```
string myString = @"This is the first line

This is the third line as the 2nd is empty
The string continues

Anso so on ...
...
..
.";
```

I know that I can split this into an array, delete the first 2 elements and then rebuild my string from that array but I'm looking for something much more simple.

Comment: It doesn't really get any simpler than `string.Split('\n')` and removing the desired indexes.

Comment: `String.Join("\n", myString.Split('\n').Skip(2))`

Comment: I suppose you could call `IndexOf` twice to get the position of the second `\r\n` and then `Substring` from there..

Answer (score 4):

```
myString = String.Join("\n", myString.Split('\n').Skip(2));
```

[Here's @maccettura's fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/58HrI0) of that code with your string literal.

To break that down:

1. Split on newlines, return a sequence of segments -- the segments are lines, since we split on newline:

   ```
   myString.Split('\n')
   ```
2. Skip the first two segments, return the rest of the a sequence

   ```
   .Skip(2)
   ```
3. And rejoin the shorter sequence with newlines:

   ```
   String.Join("\n", ...
   ```

This is just what you were contemplating doing in a loop, but with `Skip()`, it can be expressed as a readable one-liner.

Lastly, here's @user1242967 's version of the Split() call, which will handle `\r\n` newlines:

```
myString.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: Unless OP needs to micro-optimize memory consumption, this is the cleanest way of doing it.

Comment: Made a fiddle if you wanna include it in your answer: https://dotnetfiddle.net/58HrI0

Comment: @maccettura Thank you. Added.

Comment: Use 
myString.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
to handle different types of newlines.

Comment: @user1242967 Actually \n will work on \r\n since the \n comes after the \r.  The real trick is if you need to handle \n or \r or \r\n.

Comment: Ed, your first method worked like a charm but @user1242967's solution did not. My string has "\r\n" as a line separator.

Answer (score 1):

If you *do* want to micro-optimize (or your strings are large, or you're calling this in a loop), here is a more performant way to do it:

```
private static string RemoveFirstTwoLines(string myString) {
    int ix = myString.IndexOf('\n');
    ix = myString.IndexOf('\n', ix + 1);
    return myString.Substring(ix + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good for large strings, code easy to read:

```
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var text = "line 1\r\nline 2\r\nline 3\r\nline 4";

            using (var sr = new StringReader (text))
            {
                sr.ReadLine ();
                sr.ReadLine ();

                string result = sr.ReadToEnd ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```